# Looking for an OpenID provider with CNAME and personal certificate support

Tags: openid

Is there an OpenID provider which supports:

- Authentication based on personal certificates, installed in the browser
- Possibility of using your own domain with a CNAME to perform delegation, instead of having to host a page with the delegation HTML tags.

I'm using MyOpenID currently which supports the latter and in theory supports the former, but it's not working for at least two years.